# Laravel 5 form URL creation

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Working on trying to get the following form's URL to populate properly. Been stumbling over this for some time so here for some help.

As you can see from the following code, I am opening the form - binding the model - and trying to set the URL dynamically. the full URL is something like {username}/account/cards/id so i need to pass it the username (which i would like to pass the authenticated user (as they would only have access to their own page) and the ID of the card they are trying to update.

```
{!! Form::model($card, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' =>  'Account\CardsController@update', array(Auth::user()->username, $card->id) ]) !!}
```

Now this is all happening in blade (front end) so not 100% what i am doing wrong. I have tried action, url, route... I can not get anything to work for some reason. Error I am getting on this one specifically is a array to string error.  But if I can't build an array how do i pass in multiple variables? So a bit confused here.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Citti

Comment: Have you tried using the `route()` helper? So that your code will look like this `'action' => route('card_update_route', ['username'=> Auth::user()->username, 'id' => $card->id])`

Comment: {!! Form::model($card, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' =>  route('{username}.account.cards.update', ['username' => Auth::user()->username, 'cards' => $card->id]) ] ) !!} 

getting the following error: 

ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 540:
Action App\Http\Controllers\http://dev.newsite.com/citti/account/cards/1 not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an update to my previous answer. You can try this one:

```
{!! Form::model($card, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' =>  [ 'Account\CardsController@update', Auth::user()->username, $card->id] ]) !!}
```

Comment: yes that is able to create the correct URL but this does not work in the context of the form helper.  The following: 


                        {!! Form::model($card, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' =>  route('update_account_card', ['username' => Auth::user()->username, 'cards' => $card->id]) ] ) !!}


throws a not defined and an invalidargumentexception

Comment: That is it. Now I am trying to think of your original answer so i can see what i was doing wrong. I think you just had that wrapped in an array() . regardless, this is working perfectly now! thanks for your help man!

Answer (score 0):

You're just passing your route parameters as an option to the `Form::model` tag, not the route. Try:

```
{!! Form::model($card, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' =>  [ 'Account\CardsController@update', [Auth::user()->username, $card->id] ] ]) !!}
```

If you're still having trouble I would suggest you name your route and reference the named route in the action.

Comment: for more complex actions is it best practice to name your routes? Just curious. Been going through beginning tutorials and they never really touch on any of this.

Comment: still getting the following error: ErrorException in helpers.php line 546:
Array to string conversion (View:

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the action should be an array if you are passing variables through to the controller. Ex:

```
{!! Form::model($card, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'action' =>  array('Account\CardsController@update', Auth::user()->username, $card->id))) !!}
```

Not sure if you are using Larvel Collective HTML and Forms, but they are essentially the same as the Laravel version. This page: http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#form-model-binding explains more about your particular use case.

Hope it helps.

P.S. Try adding:

```
{!! Form::hidden('_method', 'PATCH') !!}
```

...underneath the open tag instead of within it. This has to do with L5 method spoofing, and is generally necessary for anything that is not 'POST' or 'GET', I believe. (i.e., 'PUT', 'PATCH', and 'DELETE')